# What's going on with the user summary page on StackOverflow?

Tags: support, profile-page

Has there been a redesign of the User Summary page that only applies to StackOverflow?

I couldn't find any mention of this from a search on meta.

Or have I somehow changed a preference setting somewhere that changes the view I see? When visiting my own profile page (but not that of other people) it looks as follows.

[image]

The helpful flags count has disappeared as well as the information about consecutive visits. I don't see this on my profile on other sites.

Comment: Click on "more info".

Comment: @CodyGray - Thanks. Now I feel dumb.

Comment: That got me once; I was like, all, WTF?!?! Where'd my pretty profile go!?

Comment: @AndrewBarber - Thanks. Comforting to know that it's not just me!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You probably clicked on *less info* next to your display name. Just click on *more info* at the same place.

> [image]

Comment: Doh! Thanks. I was honestly baffled for about an hour before finally posting on meta.

Comment: @MartinSmith no worry, happens to the best! :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd BTW, I prefer your _blue_ wizard!

Comment: @bluefeet of course... if I change back to the blue will you change your display name to redfeet? ;)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd soooo very tempting! :)   I will have to think about that request!

Comment: @blu if you take the leap let me know! :-)

Comment: @blu OK, you won... back to blue and a new game. :-)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd ooo, I like that game!

Comment: @bluefeet cheers, adding profanity filter now so don't play it dirty just yet! :-D

Comment: And done, @blue - feel free to try and bypass the filter! :P