# Is it just me, or did the user profile layout just change (to a collapsed bar)?

Tags: support, profile-page

[image: Screenshot]

I hope this isn't how the profile is supposed to look, whether now or as intended for rollout in the future.

Comment: You umm, collapsed the view. Probably clicked on the 'Less Info' link next to your name by mistake.

Comment: ... does anyone actually *ever* use that view? I've always wondered why the option to toggle even exists...

Comment: @Matt Evidence at hand indicates that at least one person has used it, however unwittingly.

Comment: I had never even noticed that link before.

Comment: @TimPost Probably me. I click every button and link I see :P

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192447/whats-going-on-with-the-user-summary-page-on-stackoverflow but this one has a better title so I guess I'll close that one.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn is that the healthy way to go?, I looks unfairly unfair to the other question, maybe it just deserved a title change or something, I would be upset if that happened to me

Comment: @ajax333221 do you think Martin cares that his question from August got closed?  Surely he got his answer long ago, and the only thing that happens when a question is closed is that it can no longer accept new answers. Whooptee.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Click the *more info* link next to your user name to switch back to standard.

Comment: I'm going to retire from the programming industry now.

Comment: No, don't do that.